Can not build admin CMS due to core.js issue
We recently upgraded to sulu cms 2.4.20 (I know, it is outdated) and are trying to manually build the admin js.
Unfortunatly we get the following very persistent errors connected to the jsrouting-bundle:
Build administration interface assets
-------------------------------------


> sulu-skeleton@ build /assets/admin
> webpack --mode production

   1406 modules

WARNING in ./node_modules/sulu-admin-bundle/services/ResourceRequester/registries/resourceRouteRegistry.js 28:4-18
"export 'default' (imported as 'symfonyRouting') was not found in 'fos-jsrouting/router'

WARNING in ./node_modules/sulu-admin-bundle/services/ResourceRequester/registries/resourceRouteRegistry.js 41:11-25
"export 'default' (imported as 'symfonyRouting') was not found in 'fos-jsrouting/router'

WARNING in ./node_modules/sulu-admin-bundle/services/ResourceRequester/registries/resourceRouteRegistry.js 51:11-25
"export 'default' (imported as 'symfonyRouting') was not found in 'fos-jsrouting/router'

WARNING in ./node_modules/sulu-media-bundle/containers/ImageMap/ImageRenderer.js 97:11-25
"export 'default' (imported as 'symfonyRouting') was not found in 'fos-jsrouting/router'

WARNING in ./node_modules/sulu-admin-bundle/stores/metadataStore/metadataStore.js 27:18-32
"export 'default' (imported as 'symfonyRouting') was not found in 'fos-jsrouting/router'

WARNING in ./node_modules/sulu-admin-bundle/containers/Badge/stores/BadgeStore.js 88:11-25
"export 'default' (imported as 'symfonyRouting') was not found in 'fos-jsrouting/router'

WARNING in ./node_modules/sulu-admin-bundle/views/List/toolbarActions/UploadToolbarAction.js 154:11-25
"export 'default' (imported as 'symfonyRouting') was not found in 'fos-jsrouting/router'

ERROR in /vendor/friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle/Resources/public/js/router.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/modules/es.array.push.js' in '/Users/andreas/Workdata/DWBN-IT/sulu/sulu/vendor/friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle/Resources/public/js'

ERROR in /vendor/friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle/Resources/public/js/router.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/modules/esnext.iterator.constructor.js' in '/Users/andreas/Workdata/DWBN-IT/sulu/sulu/vendor/friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle/Resources/public/js'

ERROR in /vendor/friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle/Resources/public/js/router.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/modules/esnext.iterator.for-each.js' in '/Users/andreas/Workdata/DWBN-IT/sulu/sulu/vendor/friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle/Resources/public/js'

[ERROR] Unexpected error while building administration interface assets. 

I tried already everything in https://docs.sulu.io/en/2.4/cookbook/build-admin-frontend.html#common-errors, but the error persists.
Context:
node: v14.21.3
npm: 6.14.18
core-js: 3.39.0 (downgrading it to 3.18.0 as per babel.config.json does not solve the issue)
Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Same problem here. Tried building admin UI with Sulu version 2.5.8, then upgraded to 2.5.21 (including skeleton files as necessary). Tried building using the console command, using docker, and using npm locally, deleting build assets and clearing the npm cache. It's always showing the same errors. Using node v14.21.3 and npm 6.14.18 on Ubuntu 22.04.

I've just added PR which should fix the issue:
https://github.com/sulu/sulu/pull/7639
Problem is in babel loading, as @Alexander Schranz suggested.
In the meantime, until PR get's merged, you can also modify your local webpack.config.js inside admin assets folder and rebuild admin (don't replace your local webpack.config.js when prompted):
/* eslint-disable flowtype/require-valid-file-annotation */
/* eslint-disable import/no-nodejs-modules*/
/* eslint-disable no-undef */
const path = require('path');
const webpackConfig = require('../../vendor/sulu/sulu/webpack.config.js');

module.exports = (env, argv) => {
    env = env ? env : {};
    argv = argv ? argv : {};

    env.project_root_path = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..');
    env.node_modules_path = path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules');

    const config = webpackConfig(env, argv);
    config.entry = path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.js');

    config.module.rules = config.module.rules.map((rule) => {
        if (rule?.use?.loader === 'babel-loader') {
            let exclude = [rule.exclude, /friendsofsymfony\/jsrouting-bundle/];
            rule.exclude = exclude;
        }
        return rule;
    });

    return config;
};


The issue seems be somewhere in the babel loading. So changing the webpack config should be possible to fix this by excluding the fos js routing bundle package:
diff --git a/webpack.config.js b/webpack.config.js
index 06a551f3fb..3a2e6e782e 100644
--- a/webpack.config.js
+++ b/webpack.config.js
@@ -90,7 +90,10 @@ module.exports = (env, argv) => { // eslint-disable-line no-undef
                 {
                     test: /\.js$/,
                     // eslint-disable-next-line max-len
-                    exclude: /node_modules[/\\](?!(sulu-(.*)-bundle|@ckeditor|ckeditor5|array-move|lodash-es|vanilla-colorful)[/\\])/,
+                    exclude: [
+                        /node_modules[/\\](?!(sulu-(.*)-bundle|@ckeditor|ckeditor5|array-move|lodash-es|vanilla-colorful)[/\\])/,
+                        /friendsofsymfony\/jsrouting-bundle/,
+                    ],
                     use: {
                         loader: 'babel-loader',
                         options: {


Thanks for the hint @AlexanderSchranz. I tried this and replaced the corresponding part in vendor/sulu/sulu/webpack.config.js (hope, that's the right place to do it? Just for debugging, of course). Now bin/console sulu:admin:update-build produces different errors all about unexpected tokens (usage of ?? operator, it seems) found in different files related to package react-leaflet. The output suggests to configure the required webpack loaders.

To narrow down the source of the problems, I now tried this: installed a fresh Ubuntu 24.04 on a new virtual server, installed PHP 8.3 CLI + required extensions, composer, nodejs (18) and npm (9). Then created a fresh Sulu project using 2.6 version. Added a small change to assets/admin/app.js and tried to build the admin. The same errors occur as mentioned in the original question.

I have added the fix to vendor/sulu/sulu/webpack.config.js now and rebuild the admin. This time it worked. So, at least for Sulu 2.6 with default software versions on Ubuntu 24.04 it's fine when excluding fosrouting. Will now try Sulu 2.5 with Ubuntu 22.04, Node 14 and NPM 6.

Tested now with Sulu 2.5, Ubuntu 22.04, PHP 8.1, Node 14, NPM 6. Including the fix to webpack.config.js, the errors related to fosrouting do not occur, but the errors related to unexpected tokens in react-leaflet do. But these two problems might be unrelated. I will create another bug report for Sulu.

This has been sorted out. If you are using Sulu 2.5.x, make sure to use the correct lines in webpack.config.js. See: https://github.com/sulu/sulu/issues/7636#issuecomment-2454230644
